# C++ Macro code substitution

Tags: c++, macros

1) - i have two enums

```
enum FixedScriptingEvent {
    FIXED_SCRIPTING_EVENT_NOTOUCH,  
    FIXED_SCRIPTING_EVENT_OVER_MOVED,
    FIXED_SCRIPTING_EVENT_OVER_RELEASED,    
    FIXED_SCRIPTING_EVENT_OUTSIDE_RELEASED,
    FIXED_SCRIPTING_EVENT_OUTSIDE_MOVED,    
...

enum InputState {

    INPUT_STATE_NOTOUCH,
    INPUT_STATE_OVER_MOVED,
    INPUT_STATE_OVER_RELEASED,
    INPUT_STATE_OUTSIDE_RELEASED,
    INPUT_STATE_OUTSIDE_MOVED,  
    INPUT_STATE_OUTSIDE_PRESSED,
...
```

2) i have an association between these two macros and need to call this code for each

```
if (inputMonitor.state.current == INPUT_STATE_NOTOUCH) {
    executeScriptsForEvent( FIXED_SCRIPTING_EVENT_INPUT_STATE_CHANGED_TO_NOTOUCH );
}
if (inputMonitor.state.current == INPUT_STATE_MOVED) {
    executeScriptsForEvent( FIXED_SCRIPTING_EVENT_INPUT_STATE_CHANGED_TO_MOVED );
}
```

3) so i made this macro

```
    #define EXECUTEFIXEDSCRIPTEVENTFORSTATE(x, y) if (inputMonitor.state.current == x) {executeScriptsForEvent( y );}

    EXECUTEFIXEDSCRIPTEVENTFORSTATE(INPUT_STATE_NOTOUCH, FIXED_SCRIPTING_EVENT_INPUT_STATE_CHANGED_TO_NOTOUCH);
    EXECUTEFIXEDSCRIPTEVENTFORSTATE(INPUT_STATE_OVER_MOVED, FIXED_SCRIPTING_EVENT_INPUT_STATE_CHANGED_TO_OVER_MOVED);
    EXECUTEFIXEDSCRIPTEVENTFORSTATE(INPUT_STATE_OVER_RELEASED, FIXED_SCRIPTING_EVENT_INPUT_STATE_CHANGED_TO_OVER_RELEASED);

    #undef EXECUTEFIXEDSCRIPTEVENTFORSTATE(x, y)
```

which is fine

**4) the question, how can i do smth like this**

```
#define EXECUTEFIXEDSCRIPTEVENTFORSTATE(x)\
if (inputMonitor.state.current == INPUT_STATE_(x)) {\
executeScriptsForEvent( FIXED_SCRIPTING_EVENT_INPUT_STATE_CHANGED_TO_(x) );
}\
```

so i only need to

```
    EXECUTEFIXEDSCRIPTEVENTFORSTATE(NOTOUCH);
```

which should be equivalent to my current :

```
EXECUTEFIXEDSCRIPTEVENTFORSTATE(INPUT_STATE_NOTOUCH, FIXED_SCRIPTING_EVENT_INPUT_STATE_CHANGED_TO_NOTOUCH);
```

**but the compiler states that NOTOUCH is not defined, so i cant the macro from 4**

Comment: i cant use the macro from 4, because the compiler says that NOTOUCH is not defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Token concatenation?

```
#define EXECUTEFIXEDSCRIPTEVENTFORSTATE(x)\
if (inputMonitor.state.current == INPUT_STATE_ ## x) {\
executeScriptsForEvent(FIXED_SCRIPTING_EVENT_INPUT_STATE_CHANGED_TO_ ## x);\
}
```